# Finding my Linux shared libraries at runtime

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm porting an SDK written in C++ from Windows to Linux.  There are other binaries, but at its simplest, our SDK is this:

- core.dll - implicitly loaded DLL ("libcore.so" shared library on Linux)
- tests.exe - an app use to test the DLL (uses google test)

All of my binaries must live in ***one*** folder somewhere that apps can find.   I've achieved that on Windows.  I wanted to achieve the same thing in Linux.  I'm failing miserably

To illustrate, Here's the basic project tree.  We use CMake.  After I build I've got

```
mysdk
  |---CMakeLists.txt (has add_subdirectory() statements for "tests" and "core")
  |---/tests  (source code + CMakeLists.txt)
  |---/core   (source code + CMakeLists.txt)
  |---/build  (all build ouput, CMake output, etc)
        |---tests  (build output)
        |---core   (build output)
```

The goal is to "flatten" the "build" tree and put all the binary outputs of tests, core, etc into one folder.

1. I tried adding CMake's "install" command, to each of my `CMakeLists.txt` files (e.g. `install(TARGETS core DESTINATION bin`).  I then then executed `sudo make install` after my normal build.  This put all my binaries in `/usr/local/bin` with no errors.  But when I ran `tests` from there, it failed to find `libcore.so`, even though it was sitting right there in the same folder

> ```
> tests: error while loading shared libraries: libcore.so: Cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```

2. I read up on the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and so tried adding that folder (`/usr/local/bin`) into it and running.  I can see I've properly altered `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it still doesn't work.  "tests" still can't find `libcore.so`.  I even tried changing the PATH environment variable as well.  Same result.
3. In frustration, I tried brute-force copying the output binaries to a temporary subfolder (of `/mysdk/build`) and running `tests` from there.  To my surprise it ran.
   Then I realized why:  Instead of loading the local copy of `libcore.so` it had loaded the one from the build output folder (as if the full path were "baked in" to the app at build time).  Subsequently deleting that build-output copy of `libcore.so` made "tests" fail altogether as before, instead of loading the local copy.   So maybe the path really *was* baked in.

I'm at a loss. I've read the CMake tutorial and reference.  It makes this sound so easy.   Aside from the obvious (What am I doing wrong?) I would appreciate if anyone could answer any of the following questions:

1. What is the correct way to control where my app looks for my shared libraries?
2. Is there a relationship between my project build structure and how my binaries must then appear when installed?
3. Am I even close to the right way of doing this?
4. Is it possible I've somehow inadvertently "baked" (into my app) full paths to my shared libraries?  Is that a thing?  I use all CMAKE variables in my CMakeLists files.

Comment: What's the output of `objdump -p /usr/local/bin/tests | grep RPATH` ?  (It's normal for the in-build executable to have `RPATH` set to include paths to local libraries it's linked in; but for the installed executable, unless you've set some CMake variable related to `RPATH` then it shouldn't have an `RPATH` set.)  Normally, you should be installing local shared libraries into `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/lib`, so `/usr/local/lib` in this case.

Comment: Oh, or it's possible the libraries should go into `/usr/local/lib64` or `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` - the latter for Debian or Ubuntu or Mint, etc., the former for most other distributions.  If you `include(GNUInstallDirs)` and then `install(TARGET core DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})` that should take care of those variations, I think.

Comment: _"I can see I've properly altered `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it still doesn't work."_ How can you see that? Have you done `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make it visible in child processes, not just the current shell? If you'd done it properly it would work.

Comment: Read `man ld.so` for other ways to find shared libraries, with various pros and cons compared to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. There are some docs at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic which describe finding GCC's libs, but apply to any shared libs.

Comment: @DanielSchepler - the output of that command is... nothing.  Literally nothing.  I triple checked the syntax and that the file is there.  However "J B"s approach of using ldd does dump dependencies.  Oddly it shows it referring to files that are already there.   I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.  I appreciate the bit about the directories.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - I did not realize that you need to use export to make it visible to child processes.  I was thinking like a Windows developer (i.e. just set environment variable and child processes get it).  Sadly, using export does not appear to anything.  Thanks for the reference.  It looks like I've got a lot more reading to do.

Comment: OK, the fact that the command returned empty output just means that the executable has no RPATH set, which is as expected.  So what remains is to make sure the shared library is installed into a directory that's searched by the dynamic loader by default - which unlike Windows, does not include `/usr/local/bin` (either absolutely, as part of the `PATH` variable, or as the directory containing the executable).

Answer (score 2):

You can run `ldd file` to print the shared object dependencies for `file`. It will tell you where are its dependencies being read from.

You can export the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the paths you want the linker to look for. If a dependency is not found, try adding the path where that dependency is located at to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then run `ldd` again (make sure you export the variable).

Also, make sure the dependencies have the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Updating **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** is an option. Another option is using RPATH. Please check the example.

https://github.com/mustafagonul/cmake-examples/blob/master/005-executable-with-shared-library/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Project
project(005-executable-with-shared-library)

# Directories
set(example_BIN_DIR bin)
set(example_INC_DIR include)
set(example_LIB_DIR lib)
set(example_SRC_DIR src)

# Library files
set(library_SOURCES ${example_SRC_DIR}/library.cpp)
set(library_HEADERS ${example_INC_DIR}/library.h)
set(executable_SOURCES ${example_SRC_DIR}/main.cpp)

# Setting RPATH
# See https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${example_LIB_DIR})

# Add library to project
add_library(library SHARED ${library_SOURCES})

# Include directories
target_include_directories(library PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${example_INC_DIR})

# Add executable to project
add_executable(executable ${executable_SOURCES})

# Linking
target_link_libraries(executable PRIVATE library)

# Install
install(TARGETS executable DESTINATION ${example_BIN_DIR})
install(TARGETS library DESTINATION ${example_LIB_DIR})
install(FILES ${library_HEADERS} DESTINATION ${example_INC_DIR})
```